# How to always enable my Hibernate filters in a spring application?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hibernate-filters

Having a Hibernate (3.5)/Spring (3.0)/BlazeDS/Flex stack-based application, I need to apply filters for some of my domain classes as shown below.

```
@FilterDef(name="notDeletedFilter")
@Filter(name="notDeletedFilter", condition="deleted=0")
public class Item {
   private boolean deleted;
  //setter and getter
}
```

These filters should always be applied in my application. 
However, according to the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html), by default, filters are not enabled for a given hibernate session.

So my question is very simple: How can I **enable all defined hibernate filters as above for all Hibernate sessions**? Is there anyway to configure my Hibernate Session factory in a spring xml configuration file in order to apply these filters?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring's HibernateTemplate, one solution is to extend it and override the enableFilters method.  In it, explicitly enable the filters you need.

Comment: Yes we are using HibernateTemplate. But the issue is to explicitely enable each filter by name. Is it possible to configure HibernateTemplate such that it will enable ALL filters?

Comment: HibernateTemplate.setFilterName(String) or HibernateTemplate.setFilterNames(String[])

Comment: SessionFactory.getDefinedFilterNames will give the set of all filter names, you can use that in conjuction with enableFilters

Comment: I have this exact problem. What if i don't use Hibernate Template?

Answer (score 0):

You could use AOP (aspect oriented programming) to configure the filter.

Comment: Can you please elaborate litle on this?